# How to fail or pass a unit test based on the amount of time it takes to run?

Tags: karma-jasmine

When looking at the matchers, there are methods like `toHaveBeenCalled()`, `toHaveBeenCalledWith()`, `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` .... What if I want to fail or pass a test based on the amount of time it takes to run it?

```
it('should run within x seconds', (done) => {
   sut.someLongRunningMethod().subscribe(() =>
      //expect() to run within x seconds...
   });
});
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you looking for `it(description, testFunctionopt, timeoutopt)`?

Comment: Maybe. I really don't know how to tackle it. There's nothing really I see that I can use.